# GCP GPU nvidia P100 instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine, nvidia, tesla

recently google approved my quota for 4 nvidia tesla p100 on a project i'm working(so I have the quota).

The issue is that i don't know how is called the nvidia p100 in gcp, and i can't find it anywhere. i'm making the instance like this.

```
gcloud beta compute instances create instance-1
--machine-type n1-standard-2
--zone europe-west1-b
--accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-p100-gpus,count=4 
--image-family ubuntu-1604-lts
--image-project ubuntu-os-cloud
--maintenance-policy TERMINATE
```

Does anyone know how to make the right instance?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the command 'type' option from `type=nvidia-tesla-p100-gpus,count=4` to `type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=4`